# Run keyup function() based on keyCode except in input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a quick button on the blog. Some buttons have their respective functions defined by the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).keyup(function(cfunc) {
    if (cfunc.keyCode == 83) {
        alert("S button");
    }
    if (cfunc.keyCode == 84) {
        alert("T button");
    }
    if (cfunc.keyCode == 67) {
        alert("C button");
    }
});
</script>
```

The code above works well. But there is a bit of a problem. If we enter text into the input field, then this code will interfere. Can we just run code outside the input field?

For example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="abcd test"/>
```

If we enter the text `"abcd test"`, it will appear alert several times. This is because there are buttons `s, t, and c`.
How to fix this code?

Comment: `$(document).not(':input').keyup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to prevent that is by checking if an input or textarea is focused:

```js
$(document).keyup(function(cfunc) {
    if ($("textarea, input").is(":focus")) { return; }
    if (cfunc.keyCode == 83) {
        alert("S button");
    }
    if (cfunc.keyCode == 84) {
        alert("T button");
    }
    if (cfunc.keyCode == 67) {
        alert("C button");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<br />
<textarea>hey</textarea>
```